# socket.io and pm2 : how does version number in node.js works?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

when I run

```
node -v
```

**I got 4.2.1** which is very strange since I remember I worked with 0.10 versions: I am totally lost with nodejs versions

reading the pm2 doc

> Warning: If you want to use the embedded load balancer (cluster mode),
>   we recommend the use of node#0.12.0+ or node#0.11.16+. We do not
>   support node#0.10.*'s cluster module anymore.

- I don't understand how node.js versions works: looks like we jumped form 0.10 
  to 4.2
- Does pm2 works with latest version of node.js ?

regards

Comment: Due to the io.js fork followed by a merge, a jump was necessary, yes.

Comment: ok.. What about: "Warning: If you want to use the embedded load balancer (cluster mode), we recommend the use of node#0.12.0+ or node#0.11.16+. We do not support node#0.10.*'s cluster module anymore" what about version 4.2.1 ? And what is the history of node.JS ? 0.10 ->0.11->0.12->4.0 ?

Comment: 0.12 was usual node.js. There was a node.js fork called io.js. After they decided to merge they went with 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

> don't understand how node.js versions works: looks like we jumped form 0.10 to 4.2

When io.js and node.js merged, then node.js jump directly to 4.x series. This happened due to difference in versions of io.js (3.x series) and node.js (0.x series). So next common version was named 4.x series and this lead to some confusion. See [this announcement](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/foundation-v4-announce/).

> Does pm2 works with latest version of node.js ?

You can give it a try yourself, but IMO it should work well.

Comment: Similar question on quora  https://www.quora.com/Why-did-node-stable-version-number-jumps-from-directly-0-12-x-to-4-x

Answer (score 0):

At the end of 2014, [node was forked into io.js](https://iojs.org/en/faq.html) for reasons I won't cover here.

The io.js project adopted the semver notation and, as the pace of changes was very fast (we got all the recent advances of ES6 that were already available in V8), came to version 3.

In september 2015, io.js was merged back into node, and it was decided to keep the semver versionning, and to go to version 4. [More details here, including the LTS](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-is-semver).

This makes it possible to deal with a monotonous version order, thus a 4.0 version of node is greater than a 0.11 version. But be wary, many changes were introduced and the ecosystem is big. You'll probably have changes to do when going from 0.x to a new version, especially if you use many modules.